# Jenkins declarative pipeline incorrect svn change list

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a freestyle project I'm trying to move to a declarative pipeline project in jenkins.  It uses SVN and the project is set up to poll the SVN repo and use a Jenkins file from the SCM for configuration.  All of this works correctly.

My issue is that the change set for each build includes 4 copies of all of the changes that went into the last successful build as well.  This didn't happen with the original freestyle job.  While this is a bit annoying, where it really becomes a problem is that now all of these changes and authors become culprits when the builds fail so everyone gets email rather than just the most recent changes.  The changes listed for each build span months and each new build adds it's changes to the full list.

For example, if I look at recent changes on this project I see 4 copies of build # 60 with a bunch of changes that were already in build #59, and then 4 copies of build #59 with :

```
#60 (build timestamp)
20967. fixing a typos in xxxxx          <-- This is the only new change
20930. Reverted to 19901                <-- in build #59
20793. Temporary change to debug xxxx   <-- in build #59 or #58 etc
20775. Add xxx block and xx to xxx      <-- in build #59 or #58 etc
...
# #60 (build timestamp)                 <-- Duplicate of the last entry
20967. fixing a typos in xxxxx
20930. Reverted to 19901
20793. Temporary change to debug xxxx
20775. Add xxx block and xx to xxx
...
# #60 (build timestamp)
20967. fixing a typos in xxxxx
20930. Reverted to 19901
20793. Temporary change to debug xxxx
20775. Add xxx block and xx to xxx
...
# #60 (build timestamp)
20967. fixing a typos in xxxxx
20930. Reverted to 19901
20793. Temporary change to debug xxxx
20775. Add xxx block and xx to xxx
...

# #59 (build timestamp)                   <-- Previous build
20930. Reverted to 19901
20793. Temporary change to debug xxxx
20775. Add xxx block and xx to xxx
...
# #59 (build timestamp)
20930. Reverted to 19901
20793. Temporary change to debug xxxx
20775. Add xxx block and xx to xxx
...
# #59 (build timestamp)
20930. Reverted to 19901
20793. Temporary change to debug xxxx
20775. Add xxx block and xx to xxx
...
# #59 (build timestamp)
20930. Reverted to 19901
20793. Temporary change to debug xxxx
20775. Add xxx block and xx to xxx
...
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: did you try with this ...`def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets`  should give you only the current builds changes

Comment: I tried putting that in a script {} block in the pipeline and it made no difference to my behavior

Comment: Does it give back a value ? Or is it empty?